# using puppeteer-recorder to record video of browser

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to record puppeteer to see what happens when i run it on server, as I understand this package does what i want.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-recorder

so here is simplified version of my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { record } = require('puppeteer-recorder');
var path = 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\home_robot\\';

init_puppeteer();

const global_browser  ; 
async function init_puppeteer() {

        global_browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false , args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});

    check_login()
};

async function check_login()
{
    try {
        const page = await global_browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 1100});

        await record({
            browser: global_browser, // Optional: a puppeteer Browser instance,
            page: page, // Optional: a puppeteer Page instance,
            output: path + 'output.webm',
            fps: 60,
            frames: 60 * 5, // 5 seconds at 60 fps
        prepare: function () {}, // <-- add this line
        render: function () {} // <-- add this line

        });

        await page.goto('https://www.example.cob', {timeout: 60000})
            .catch(function (error) {
                throw new Error('TimeoutBrows');
            });

        await page.close();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(' LOGIN ERROR ---------------------');
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

But I get this error

```
    $ node home.js
(node:7376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn ffmpeg ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:7376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:7376) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
 LOGIN ERROR ---------------------
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:406:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:394:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:294:11)
    at Promise (C:\wamp64\www\home_robot\node_modules\puppeteer-recorder\index.j
s:72:12)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at write (C:\wamp64\www\home_robot\node_modules\puppeteer-recorder\index.js:
71:3)
    at module.exports.record (C:\wamp64\www\home_robot\node_modules\puppeteer-re
corder\index.js:44:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

i've even ran `npm i reinstall ffmpeg --with-libvpx`
 as  it was suggested here

https://github.com/clipisode/puppeteer-recorder/issues/6

but still didnt work  .... wha telse do i need to do ?

Comment: interesting. there is a way to globally record every test runned with puppeteer by jest in a single video? it can be very useful for debug purpose.

Comment: @AndreaBisello it's been a while but it didn't work as expected , video had very low frame rate  which is not odd considering its just bunch of screenshots attached to each other  ... and for some reason the "video" was very short ... its a great idea but this package is not working very good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add two empty functions called `prepare` and `render` in the options.

```
await record({
  browser: global_browser, // Optional: a puppeteer Browser instance,
  page, // Optional: a puppeteer Page instance,
  output: path + 'output.webm',
  fps: 60,
  frames: 60 * 5, // 5 seconds at 60 fps,
  prepare: function () {}, // <-- add this line
  render: function () {} // <-- add this line
});
```

Basically it's missing some default functions and the error is not handled properly.

Comment: ffmpeg is not a npm package. Check this to install ffmpeg on your windows machine https://video.stackexchange.com/a/20496

Comment: Recorded video quality is poor, with the same settings

Answer (score 10):

I know this would be a very late response to your question, but nevertheless.

A years ago, I visited this same stack-overflow thread and I had similar challenge of finding a screen recorder library which does a  good job a capturing the video as well as offers an options to manually start and stop the recording.

Finally I wrote one for myself and distributed as NPM library...!!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-screen-recorder

Hope this is helpful...!!

Comment: thanx , very useful ... and it actually works !!

Comment: thanks, i actually used that before coming here but it seems to record the video later and kind of fails to capture how long the site takes to load

Comment: what is the ```PassThrough``` ? WebStorm could not find it

Comment: Hi! Nice work! Is it possible to capture specific element? Thanks!

Comment: works like magic! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Also, there's https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-capture which uses `HeadlessExperimental` protocol.